# Answering a birthday problem using a while and for loop in R - struggling with the while loop

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

Beginner here. I am trying to answer this question in r: **How many people would you need to gather together before there is a 90% chance that one of them was born on 1st Jan?**

I started off doing the 'for' loop that determined the percentage, which works on its own, but cannot get the 'while' loop to work that will increase the number of people each time (if the percentage is not 90 yet) to work. It says that I need to define 'perc' before the loops, which makes sense but I don't know what I would define them as?

The current loop that is not working is attached - any advice on how to get the while loop working would be great.

```
n<-1
x<-0

while (perc < 90){
  n <- n + 1
  {for (i in 1:1000) {
    bdays <- sample(1:365, size=n, replace = TRUE)
    if (1 %in% bdays) score = 1 else score = 0
      x = x + score
      perc<-x/1000*100
  }}
  if (perc > 90){
    break
  }
  print(paste(n))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues:

First, you cannot perform a logical comparison on a nonexistent vector `perc`. Instead, define it before the loop:

```
perc <- 0
```

Second, you must reset `x` to be `0` at the end of each round of the `while` loop:

```
while (perc < 90){
  #...SNIP
  print(paste(n))
  x <- 0
}
```

Otherwise, `x` just keeps getting added to between rounds.

Finally, date of birth is not a uniform distribution. See [here](https://www.panix.com/%7Emurphy/bday.html)

Comment: Thank you! It finally runs (and with sensible answers). It currently prints every n number until it has finished the total that gives me 90%, is there any easy way to just print the final answer?

Comment: Move `print(paste(n))` outside the loop. Then it only prints the final (correct) number.